# Como establecer un rango o restricción para el ingreso de datos en java?

Tags: java

necesito generar un rango para el ingreso de las notas ya que no pueden mayores que 100 ni menores que 0 , pero no se como definir eso ¿alguno consejo sobre como hacer ese rango (0-100)? gracias.

```
import java.util.*;

class Calificacion{   
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nota1 , nota2 , nota3 , promedio = 0;
    Scanner Entrada;
    Entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
       
    System.out.println("Sistema de notas");
    
    System.out.println("ingrese las notas");
    nota1 = Entrada.nextInt();
    nota2 = Entrada.nextInt();
    nota3 = Entrada.nextInt();
    
   promedio = ((nota1+nota2+nota3)/3) ;
     
    if (promedio>90 && promedio<=100  ){
        
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    else if(promedio>80 && promedio<=90  ){
        
        System.out.println("B");
    }
       else if(promedio>70 && promedio<=80  ){
        
        System.out.println("C");
    }
       else if(promedio>60 && promedio<=70  ){
        
        System.out.println("D");
    }
       else if(promedio<60 ){
        
        System.out.println("F");
    }    
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar la siguiente solución:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag =  true;
    int nota1 , nota2 , nota3 , promedio = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese una nota");
    while (flag) {
      nota1 = sc.nextInt();
      if(nota1 < 0 || nota1 > 100){
          System.out.println("Nota incorrecta, ingrese nuevamente");
          continue;
      }else{
          flag = false;
      }
    }  
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Cristian Gómez Muchas gracias!!